# How to launch a macos .app from C++ (nonblocking)?

Tags: c++, macos

What's the best way to launch a macosx .app from a C++ program, without blocking the C++ program?

ie given a macos x app at path:

```
 /somewhere/foo.app
```

How can I within a C++ program:

```
int main() {
    run_mac_app("/somewhere/foo.app"); // returns immediately

    // after main exits, foo.app continues running.
}
```

How do I implement `run_mac_app`?

Comment: Maybe `std::system("open -g /somewhere/foo.app");`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need to run in the terminal:

```
open -a /somewhere/foo.app
```

If you want this app to run in the background, then you have to add -g

```
open -g -a /somewhere/foo.app
```

So Finally,

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::system("open -g -a /somewhere/foo.app"); 
}
```

Reference from:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html